# Conditional second query in rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I have a rule in the .htaccess file that makes a shorter URL:

```
RewriteRule ^job(.*)$ /include/myfile.incl.php?proj=$1 [NC,L]
```

to make the final URL looks like:

```
mydomain.com/jobXXXXXX
```

Is it possible to accommodate second query is a user changes my URL like this?

```
mydomain.com/jobXXXXXX?token=123
```

I need to be able to pick-up that token value too then.

Perhaps there's a way to add a conditional $2 somehow? I've tried QSA flag but it did not work for me. Perhaps my Apache version is too old... 2.2.3(CentOS)

Whichever solution I could use, another rewrite rule or perhaps in combination with PHP. I'm stuck.

---

UPDATE

NM... I think the problem is in my PHP, not .htaccess

Comment: `QSA` flag should have work.

Comment: Yes, QSA looks like what I need, but I can't seem to be able to get it to work. I wonder if there's some setting on the server that prevents it.

Comment: Show us the attempt you are trying with `QSA` flag.

Comment: I think the problem is not in my .htaccess but rather PHP file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)?

```
RewriteRule ^job(.*)$ /include/myfile.incl.php?proj=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The QSA flag should work. I'm using it 5 years now.

Comment: Yes, I tried but I'm thinking that I may be trying to access the "optional" varible in some wrong way. Won't it be: $_GET['token']?

Comment: Yes, it would be that. Does it print the content `myfile.incl.php` when you add the token?

Answer (score 0):

Use %{QUERY_STRING} in your rewrite target to access the query string. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^job(.*)$ /include/myfile.incl.php?proj=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried. Nothing broke, but how do I access the optional variable?